# Website Loading Only once then access denied - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We are trying to access a website

Url=https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain using selenium.

**However, it loads only once if we reload it, we get an access denied error.**

CODE-

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
opts = Options()
user_agent =  ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) '
'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36')
opts.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
opts.add_argument('--disable-infobars')

browser  = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.get('https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain')
time.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: Looks like it is not selenium issue. Some website does not allow robot or automation and once they catch you are running the script, they block your IP address hence you may be getting Access denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some website use anti-bot protection, that can detect your bot thanks to some differencies between automated brower and standard browser.
You should try to add these settings:

```
opts.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
opts.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
opts.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
```

If this don't work, try [Undetected Chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/), it work like the standard chrome driver, but it patch it with more setting to increase stealthiness.

By the way, your user-agent looks a little bit outdated, you should sue a newer one according to your chromedriver version, like this one: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36`

Comment: The above settings didn't work, but Undetected Chrome Driver worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--disable-default-apps")
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--disable-site-isolation-trials")
options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
options.add_argument("--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu-compositing")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu-shader-disk-cache")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
# options.add_argument("--window-size=600,600")
# options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to why you wrote the answer you did.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).